# File Table Sql Server 2012 - Access to the path "*" is denied

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use a FileTable (Sql Server 2012).

Access to the path 
'`\\SRV27230\MssqlServer\SubDirectory\Images\filename.jpg`' is denied.

But

path: '`\\{ip}\MssqlServer\SubDirectory\Images\filename.jpg`' it's work.

What is problem?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a DNS issue on the server. Make sure that it's resolvable, you can check this by looking in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts and check the server name is there, if not add it then try again.

Comment: Thanks for answer, It's OK. 127.0.0.1   SRV27230

Comment: Saeid - did that fix that ?

Comment: You must also check that your SQLSERVER instances actually is listening to the localhostIP (127.0.0.1) or all Adapter IPs rather than just listening on the external IP interface (ie your network adapter)